# Can't use mysql.connector

Tags: mysql, flask, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I started to watch this cool guy's flask lessons (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Qxtt4veJIc&list=PLCC34OHNcOtolz2Vd9ZSeSXWc8Bq23yEz). I got stuck on 9th lesson, where I need to create a MySQL table. I installed :

```
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.2.0
mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2
```

using venv in VScode (on mac)

I made everything like in video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQl2wyJvK5k&t=145s), but when I start file create_db.py, I get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/create_db.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 137, in _do_auth
    packet = self._protocol.make_auth(
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 99, in make_auth
    packet += self._auth_response(client_flags, username, password,
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 58, in _auth_response
    auth = get_auth_plugin(auth_plugin)(
  File "/Users/nikitagudkov/Documents/Dev/flasker/virt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/authentication.py", line 190, in get_auth_plugin
    raise errors.NotSupportedError(
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

I think problem connected with the way I downloaded MySQl or with a password for the root? I'll be happy to get your advice!

create_db.py :

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="my_passord"
)

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("CRETE DATABASE our_users")
my_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for db in my_cursor:
    print(db)
```

requirements.txt :

```
blinker==1.6.3
click==8.1.7
Flask==3.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
Flask-WTF==1.2.1
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.2.0
mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2
protobuf==4.21.12
SQLAlchemy==2.0.22
typing_extensions==4.8.0
Werkzeug==3.0.0
WTForms==3.1.0
zipp==3.17.0
```

Comment: Definitely a version skew problem between your python connector (newer) and your database server (older).

Comment: Please keep `mysql-connector-python==8.2.0`, which is the official connector, and remove `mysql-connector==2.2.9` and `mysql-connector-python-rf==2.2.2`. I suggest to remove all and install only `mysql-connector-python==8.2.0`. Most likely, the official modules are being overwritten by the other two packages.